# AdSense ads don't show up after refreshing the page

Tags: html, google-adsense, advertising

I have developed a small CMS site.  I tested AdSense in localhost and everything worked fine but after uploading site to my server ads are not showing if i refresh a page.  Once I refresh a page, ads are just not showing up no matter what.

Here is a demo post. Ads are working fine here because I didn't refresh the page:
http://english.onetelangana.com/article.php?id=61

No ads are showing here:
http://english.onetelangana.com/article.php?id=68

What exactly is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is anything wrong with your site or your AdSense implementation.  Both pages have ads that show up for me.

Sometimes Google may choose not to show ads for one of a couple reasons:

- There are no advertisers
- Google believes that the risk of click fraud is high

The best way to know whether your ads are working or not is to monitor your AdSense reporting in the coming days.   If the ads are getting impressions and clicks, then everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The big problem is that your title tag is very short, and you have no description in your description tag that search engines try to use to describe your site.

Also, make sure that you have full legal rights to use the content on your page. Taking another news story and slapping it on your site with maybe minor cosmetic adjustments still counts as copying and might get you kicked out of the adsense program.

Also, you need to ditch the scrolling text as that is old fashioned, and add lots more english. Adsense won't work with certain countries.

And, try to make your website have a good plot in a few words. I ran your page that you had adsense problems with through the tool found at:

```
http://tools.seobook.com/general/keyword-density/
```

And its telling me that the top 5 words in your site are "The","bjp","of","in", and "telangana". I highly doubt that an advertiser would want to make a wonderful advertisement about any of those words. You might get an advertisement of a place on a rare occasion because of the word "in" (aka inside a place).

What's even crazier is that the word "the" has a keyword density of 5.75% from all the words on your page which is extremely high. It should be 1% - 4%. Anything too high might cause your page to be labeled as spammy by search engines.